# What should I do if a username contains a violent message?

Tags: discussion, display-names

I have stumbled upon this user:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/14519611/butcher-animals-drink-blood

which is a member since yesterday. The user insist on using user names, resp. profile description, containing messages involving violence.

I have reported it twice and twice an action has been taken. Though the user changes its username back to something inappropriate.

Should I keep reporting this user and what would happen next?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with them specifying they're a butcher by profession in their profile description?

Comment: @Nick, do you find `Butcher Animals - Drink Blood` appropriate?

Comment: I didn't mention their user name, you _specifically_ mentioned their *"profile description"*, and that's what I'm asking about. That said, I don't think it particularly, condones violence

Comment: @Nick, it was username: "Kill animals", profile description: "...and drink their blood".

Comment: If you report it and it gets changed by moderators and then is changed back again, report it again. If you report it and the moderators don't change it then presumably they've determined they are fine with it and you'd likely not get anywhere if you report it again when they didn't do anything last time.

Comment: You already flagged the account. As you note we took action before, and your current flag is still pending. We'll take action again if warranted (I don't immediately have time to handle the flag myself right now). There isn't anything the community can do other that that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I just would like to know the procedures and if I should keep reporting it.

Comment: @scopchanov: yes, repeated problematic behaviour can indeed be flagged again, thank you for bringing it to our attention!

Comment: I must applaud one thing: this post does not pull the offensive card like the dupe link does. It correctly calls this "inappropriate" which is a vastly better description.